# How do I properly handle custom file types in my iPad/iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Just some background on the problem:

- I am using XCode 5
- I am targeting iOS 7

I've recently registered a certain file type to be opened with my app. It works the very first time (if the app isn't running in the background) then it holds on to the old file when I try to open another one. Is there a convention I should be following? I don't really care what happens to the previous file, I just want the new one to open.

Below is how I pass the `NSURL` to my root view controller. My root view controller only uses the `url` property I created in the `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    vc.url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

All I had to do was implement `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` in my `AppDelegate`.

I made a helper function in my `ViewController` named `loadFileWithUrl:(NSURL *)filePath` and handled the new `NSURL` in there.

Here is the code from my `AppDelegate`:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [vc loadFileWithUrl:url];

    return YES;
}
```